# using let var on switch/case doesn't read first case

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement

i'm a beginner learning javascript into codeacademy and i am practising by my own.

In the code below, i use let to declare the same var with different value. I wanna use the switch/case condition and i wanna the console print me "Leandro" but i only get "Ezequiel" but if i change Ezequiel value (by purpose)  i get the default. I wanna print "Leandro"

```
    let nombre = "Leandro";
nombre = "Ezequiel";

switch (nombre){

  case "Leandro":
    console.log("Leandro")
    break;

  case "Ezequiel":
    console.log("Ezequiel")
    break;

  default:
    console.log("Adios")
}
```

Comment: because you overwrite the variable... If you want `Leandro`, you delete the line `nombre = "Ezequiel";` If you want them both, you need to use a function.

Comment: because you redefine the "nombre" variable to another value which is "Ezequiel"

Comment: but with let you can make two variables with the same name, no? i'm noob sorry xd

Comment: No, "let" is only to create a local variable. You never can have two variables with the same name, in any language

Comment: @PierreAvinain To be precise, `let` creates one local variable in the current scope. If the code is evaluated multiple times (such as in a loop or a function), it will create multiple independent variables with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable can only hold a single string. So when you do `nombre = "Ezequiel";` it overrides the last value in the variable. So if you want to have multiple names you would either need multiple variables or an array.

To be able to reuse the switch, you can make it a function and call it with the names.

```js
function getMessage(nombre) {
  switch (nombre) {

    case "Leandro":
      console.log("Leandro")
      break;

    case "Ezequiel":
      console.log("Ezequiel")
      break;

    default:
      console.log("Adios")
  }
}

let nombre1 = "Leandro";
let nombre2 = "Ezequiel";

getMessage(nombre1);
getMessage(nombre2);
```

Comment: This is the explanation that I give to your code, tell me if it is wrong and thank you very much. (I have moved let and get up to clarify)

1. First you declare the variables name 1 and name2.
2. You give the getMessage function two values ​​that are the variables above.
3. In the switch, you put "name" because it is the parameter that has the function and the function already has the values ​​of the variables.

More or less? Now if I get it, thanks

I'm trying to learn, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please study this and see when you can have two vars with the same name and why you shouldn't

```html
<script>
var nombre=""; // global var - try to assign this with let for a surprise
function test1() {
  nombre = "A"
 
}
function test2() {
  let nombre = "B"
  console.log(window.nombre,nombre)
}
test1()
console.log(window.nombre)
test2()
</script>
```